# Integral Bounds and RegionPlot3D

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

We a tough problem in class today preparing for the final exam next Monday.

$$\int_0^{\pi^{1/4}}\int_0^z\int_y^z 12y^2z^3\sin(x^4)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

I was extremely surprised that I could simply type in the bounds of the integrals as inequalities using the RegionPlot3D command.

```
RegionPlot3D[0 <= z <= π^(1/4) && 0 <= y <= z && y <= x <= z, {x, 0, π^(1/4)}, 
            {y, 0, π^(1/4)}, {z, 0, π^(1/4)}]
```

Which produced the correction region of integration.

[image]

Will this process with the bounds work for every such integral? If not, can someone provide a counterexample?

Comment: I am surprised by your surprise. What did you think the `RegionPlot3D` function was for if not this?

Comment: I'd say the only time things will mess up is when your integral limits are flipped. i.e. if you're integrating z from pi^(1/4) to 0, then your inequality is always false.

Comment: `f[x_, y_, z_] := 12 y^2 z^3 Sin[x^4]; Integrate[
 f[x, y, z] Boole[0 <= z <= \[Pi]^(1/4) && 0 <= y <= z && y <= x <= z
   ], {x, 0, \[Pi]^(1/4)}, {y, 0, \[Pi]^(1/4)}, {z, 0, \[Pi]^(1/4)}]` is more surprising :)

Answer (score 3):

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[
   0 < z < π^(1/4) && 0 < y < z &&
    y < x < z, {x, y, z}];

(int1 = Integrate[
    12 y^2 z^3 Sin[x^4],
    {x, y, z} ∈ rgn]) // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {1.38881, π/4}  *)

(int2 = Assuming[{Element[{x, y, z}, Reals]},
    Integrate[12 y^2 z^3 Sin[x^4],
     {z, 0, π^(1/4)}, {y, 0, z},
     {x, y, z}]]) // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {7.53664, π/4}  *)

int1 == int2

(*  True  *)

RegionPlot3D[rgn,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"})]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting that the integration over an implicit region is faster.